# Bookmark name not editable

Tags: manipulate, cdf-format

The bookmark's name in an embedded cdf is not editable.

I used the following code to create a cdf:

```
CDFDeploy["Test.cdf", Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}, AppearanceElements -> "BookmarksButton"], Deployed -> False]
```

Then I embedded it in a web page and tried to add a bookmark. The bookmark is created but its name is not editable. Is there any other way to get bookmark functionality in embedded cdf?

[image]

Comment: CDFs opened outside MMA/PlayerPro or without enterprise signature are limited to number type InputFields.

Comment: @Kuba, thanks for the info. Is there any simple workaround to achieve bookmarking capabilities?